# Trying to sort a list of objects by an enum properties

Tags: c#, list, sorting

I have a data structure like the following:

```
public enum Direction
{
  NONE, // SHOULD NEVER BE THIS
  UP,
  DOWN,
  LEFT,
  RIGHT
};

public struct dataStruct
{
   public Direction direction;

  public int CompareTo(dataStruct other)
  {
    return this.direction.CompareTo(other.direction);
  }
}
```

I'll have a list of dataStruct, and I want to be able to sort it according to the Direction. So all the dataStruct with UP comes first, followed by DOWN, LEFT and finally RIGHT.

I tried to sort it with the following code,

```
ListOfData.Sort(
  delegate(dataStruct obj1, dataStruct obj2)
  {
    return obj1.direction.CompareTo(obj2.direction);
  }
);
```

But this gives me an error. Am I doing something wrong?

Edit: I get the following error
ArgumentException: does not implement right interface
System.Collections.Generic.Comparer`1+DefaultComparer[dataStruct].Compare (dataStruct x, dataStruct y)

Comment: Why not just use ListOfData.OrderBy(c=>c.Direction)?

Comment: @KirillBestemyanov Added the error message that I get

Comment: List.Sort -> sorts the same list, OrderBy creates new Enumrable with sorted copy of data since he uses struct not  class to define his dataStruct

Comment: it is due to Sort don't want delegate in it's signature.

Comment: I tested your sorting code, and worked fine on my pc, 
`          ListOfData.Sort((obj1, obj2) => obj1.direction.CompareTo(obj2.direction));
 `

Answer (score 2):

Add `IComparable<dataStruct>` to struct declaration.

```
public struct dataStruct : IComparable<dataStruct>
```

And just execute

```
ListOfData.Sort()
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var x = ListOfData.OrderByDescending
              (ListOfData => (Direction)Enum.Parse(typeof(Direction), ListOfData.Direction, true));
```

or simply

```
var x = ListOfData.OrderByDescending(i=> i.Direction);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just need to sort it by the direction, this simple code works. Why do you need a `CompareTo`?:

```
public class Program
{
    public void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<dataStruct> objs = new List<dataStruct>(){
            new dataStruct{direction = Direction.DOWN, id=1},
            new dataStruct{direction = Direction.LEFT, id =2},
            new dataStruct{direction = Direction.UP, id =3},
        };

        var result = objs.OrderBy(x=>x.direction);

        foreach (var element in result)
        {
            Console.WriteLine ("{0}, {1}", element.direction, element.id);
        }
    }
}

public struct dataStruct
{
    public Direction direction;
    public int id;
    //other properties
}

public enum Direction
{
  NONE, // SHOULD NEVER BE THIS
  UP,
  DOWN,
  LEFT,
  RIGHT
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create

```
public class DirectionComparer:IComparer<TypeOfData>
{
  public int Compare(dataStruct other)
  {
    return this.direction.CompareTo(other.direction);
  }
}
```

where TypeOfData is type of elements in ListOfData

and pass instatnce of it to sort method.

```
ListOfData.Sort(new DirectionComparer());
```

Comment: this doesnt have a direction member. How does this code work?

Comment: you must specify the generic type argument   `public class DirectionComparer:IComparer<dataStruct >`

Comment: of course. But questioner don't show us type that we should compare by enum